# Checking type of Object

Tags: java, object, double, long-integer

I have `Object` which can be `double` or `long`. How I can check whether type it have?

I have tried cast `Object` to `double` but if Object is long, error will occur (and vice versa for `long`).

Comment: `double` and `long` aren't objects; do you mean `Double` and `Long`?

Comment: Note that what happens on a failed cast is not an "error", but an exception that can be caught. Do not assume you cannot do something just because you want to continue processing after an exception it can throw. I do agree that instanceof is better for class checks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (yourObject instanceof Double) { } 
if (yourObject instanceof Long) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `instanceof`:

```
if (obj instanceof double) {
   // code
}

if(obj instanceof long) {
   // code
}
```

In this way you can check at runtime which type your object is.